# Bash script to insert information after each line of block of data

Tags: bash, shell-script, lxc

I wish to write a script that would insert information from the /proc file system to a list of processes generated by top. It would be something like this:

Here is the sample output that I get from top:

```
[root@alxc5 ~]# top -n 1 -c | sed '1,7d' | head -n10
20245 1842      20   0  233m  42m  10m R 100.0  0.0   0:00.71 /usr/local/php53/bin/php index.php
19302 1842      20   0  277m  86m  10m R 100.0  0.0   0:01.81 /usr/local/php53/bin/php index.php
20153 1842      20   0  264m  79m  10m R 96.6  0.0   0:00.89 /usr/local/php54/bin/php admin-ajax.php
14390 1842      20   0  228m  43m  10m R 93.6  0.0   0:04.92 /usr/local/php54/bin/php productbrandwithoutsoap.php
20047 1841      20   0  240m  54m  10m R 90.7  0.0   0:01.29 /usr/local/php54/bin/php index.php
20117 1842      20   0  273m  87m  10m R 83.4  0.0   0:01.07 /usr/local/php54/bin/php edit.php
20295 1841      20   0  202m  36m   9m R 80.5  0.0   0:00.55 /usr/local/php53/bin/php index.php
15978 1843      20   0  259m  71m  10m S 58.5  0.0   0:02.70 /usr/local/bin/php /home/groupwa4/public_html/cron.php -mdefault
18745 1842      20   0  247m  56m  11m R 46.8  0.0   0:02.30 /usr/local/bin/php /home/sukhirug/public_html/cron.php -mdefault
10234 1842      20   0  306m  92m  43m R 42.4  0.0   1:14.51 /usr/local/php53/bin/php
[root@alxc5 ~]#
```

Here is what I would like the end result to look like:

```
[root@alxc5 ~]# top -n 1 -c | sed '1,7d' | head -n10
20245 1842      20   0  233m  42m  10m R 100.0  0.0   0:00.71 /usr/local/php53/bin/php index.php
^- Process running in $proc_info
```

Where $proc_info would be something like:

```
[root@alxc5 ~]# egrep "c[0-9]{1,5}" /proc/28339/mounts -o |uniq
c8798
[root@alxc5 ~]#
```

And here is the original content of /proc/28339/mounts:

```
[root@alxc5 ~]# cat /proc/28339/mounts
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
/dev/mapper/coregroup-c8798 / ext4 rw,noatime,nodiratime,data=ordered,jqfmt=vfsv0,usrjquota=quota.user 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
/dev/sda3 /proc/loadavg ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/sda3 /proc/cpuinfo ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,relatime,gid=1342,mode=620,ptmxmode=666 0 0
/dev/mapper/coregroup-c8798 /chroot/tmp ext4 rw,noatime,nodiratime,data=ordered,jqfmt=vfsv0,usrjquota=quota.user 0 0
/dev/mapper/coregroup-c8798 /var/suexec/baseos/chroot ext4 rw,noatime,nodiratime,data=ordered,jqfmt=vfsv0,usrjquota=quota.user 0 0
/dev/mapper/coregroup-c8798 /var/suexec/baseos/chroot/tmp ext4 rw,noatime,nodiratime,data=ordered,jqfmt=vfsv0,usrjquota=quota.user 0 0
/dev/mapper/coregroup-c8798 /var/suexec/admintes ext4 rw,noatime,nodiratime,data=ordered,jqfmt=vfsv0,usrjquota=quota.user 0 0
/dev/mapper/coregroup-c8798 /var/suexec/admintes/chroot ext4 rw,noatime,nodiratime,data=ordered,jqfmt=vfsv0,usrjquota=quota.user 0 0
/dev/mapper/coregroup-c8798 /var/suexec/admintes/chroot/tmp ext4 rw,noatime,nodiratime,data=ordered,jqfmt=vfsv0,usrjquota=quota.user 0 0
/dev/mapper/coregroup-c8798 /var/suexec/admintes/home/admintes ext4 rw,noatime,nodiratime,data=ordered,jqfmt=vfsv0,usrjquota=quota.user 0 0
/dev/mapper/coregroup-c8798 /var/suexec/dancho ext4 rw,noatime,nodiratime,data=ordered,jqfmt=vfsv0,usrjquota=quota.user 0 0
/dev/mapper/coregroup-c8798 /var/suexec/dancho/chroot ext4 rw,noatime,nodiratime,data=ordered,jqfmt=vfsv0,usrjquota=quota.user 0 0
/dev/mapper/coregroup-c8798 /var/suexec/dancho/chroot/tmp ext4 rw,noatime,nodiratime,data=ordered,jqfmt=vfsv0,usrjquota=quota.user 0 0
/dev/mapper/coregroup-c8798 /var/suexec/dancho/home/dancho ext4 rw,noatime,nodiratime,data=ordered,jqfmt=vfsv0,usrjquota=quota.user 0 0
/dev/mapper/coregroup-c8798 /var/suexec/sgadmins ext4 rw,noatime,nodiratime,data=ordered,jqfmt=vfsv0,usrjquota=quota.user 0 0
/dev/mapper/coregroup-c8798 /var/suexec/sgadmins/chroot ext4 rw,noatime,nodiratime,data=ordered,jqfmt=vfsv0,usrjquota=quota.user 0 0
/dev/mapper/coregroup-c8798 /var/suexec/sgadmins/chroot/tmp ext4 rw,noatime,nodiratime,data=ordered,jqfmt=vfsv0,usrjquota=quota.user 0 0
/dev/mapper/coregroup-c8798 /var/suexec/sgadmins/home/sgadmins ext4 rw,noatime,nodiratime,data=ordered,jqfmt=vfsv0,usrjquota=quota.user 0 0
/dev/mapper/coregroup-c8798 /var/suexec/synthesi ext4 rw,noatime,nodiratime,data=ordered,jqfmt=vfsv0,usrjquota=quota.user 0 0
/dev/mapper/coregroup-c8798 /var/suexec/synthesi/chroot ext4 rw,noatime,nodiratime,data=ordered,jqfmt=vfsv0,usrjquota=quota.user 0 0
/dev/mapper/coregroup-c8798 /var/suexec/synthesi/chroot/tmp ext4 rw,noatime,nodiratime,data=ordered,jqfmt=vfsv0,usrjquota=quota.user 0 0
/dev/mapper/coregroup-c8798 /var/suexec/synthesi/home/synthesi ext4 rw,noatime,nodiratime,data=ordered,jqfmt=vfsv0,usrjquota=quota.user 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,relatime,uid=1337,gid=1337 0 0
[root@alxc5 ~]#
```

Any suggestions on how to proceed with that task are highly appreciated !

Comment: What PIDs? All of them or only the top 3? What information would you need?

Comment: @terdon I would need the information from /proc/$pid/mounts, so that I can match the process ID with the mountpoint (lxc, containers) from which the process is started. I would need to do this for all of the PIDs, not just the top 3. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: OK, please [edit] your question and make that clear. Do you want _everything_ in the mounts file? for every PID? Most of them will be the same. Ideally, [edit] your question and show us a minimal example of your input and the output you would like to see from it.

Comment: ok @terdon done, hope it makes more sense now :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
top -n 1 -c | sed '1,7d' | 
    awk '1;k=system("grep -Eo \"c[0-9]{1,5}\" /proc/$1/mounts | sort -u")'
```

The `awk` will first print each of its input lines (`1;`), then run the `grep -E` on the `/proc/PID/mounts` file. Since `top` returns whitespace-separated fields, `$1` will be the PID.

Since you're using `awk`, there's no reason to use `sed` anymore. Also, you probably want to use `top -b` to get everything and avoid artefacts due to ANSI color escapes and the like:

```
top -n 1 -bc | 
 awk 'NR<7{next}1;k=system("grep -Eo \"c[0-9]{1,5}\" /proc/$1/mounts | sort -u")'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it fits your use case:

```
man top
```

> 3. Fields/Columns
>
> > Listed below are `top`'s available process fields *(columns)*. They are
> >      shown in strict ascii alphabetical order. You may customize their
> >      position and whether or not they are displayable with the `f` or `F`
> >      *(Fields Management)* interactive commands.
> >
> > ...
> >
> > > 11. `LXC`  --  Lxc Container Name
> > >
> > > The name of the `lxc` container within which a task is running. If a process is not running inside a container, a dash *(`-`)* will be shown.

I haven't used an `lxc` container for a long time, and don't feel especially motivated to set it up again to double-check if the *`LXC`* field aligns perfectly with what you're looking for, but it sure *sounds* right.

Comment: How come my "top" utility does not have that way of formatting and sorting columns ? I can see it is part of the following package - procps-3.2.8-34.el6_7.x86_64 - what version do you have?